# Apache Solr in openshift redhat application

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, search, solr

I have a drupal application on openshift redhat server and I would like to install apache solr for my search_api_solr module. Any ideas how to do this ?

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a **minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Try including attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/118258) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the installation notes found in the [manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/apache/lucene/solr/ref-guide/apache-solr-ref-guide-5.0.pdf)?

> Installing Solr
>
> Solr is available from the Solr website at http://lucene.apache.org/solr/.Apache Solr Reference Guide 5.0 5
>   For Linux/Unix/OSX systems, download the .tgz file. For Microsoft Windows systems, download the .zip file.
>   When getting started, all you need to do is extract the Solr distribution archive to a directory of your choosing. When
>   you're ready to setup Solr for a production environment, please refer to the instructions provided on the Taking Solr
>   to Production page. To keep things simple for now, extract the Solr distribution archive to your local home
>   directory, for instance on Linux, do:

```
 $ cd ~/
 $ tar zxf solr-5.0.0.tgz
```

> Once extracted, you are now ready to run Solr using the instructions provided in the Running Solr section.

Comment: thanks, I know how to install apache solr in local application, but I don't know how install it for an application hosted on http://openshift.redhat.com/. That's my issue. Here I don't have enough permissions to set it up and I also should be able to not close my connection to server when I start solr, which is not possible.